# Thumb from video url returns null on android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, thumbnails

In my application i have to show list of videos,i have created image(thumb) from video and show that image in list.

I added code that i was used for create thumb-

```
Bitmap bitmap=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

My problem is that when i run app on android api level below 4.0 thumb is generate but when i run same application on android 4.0 and above  ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() method returns null.
Please help me how to fix this issue.

Working from yesterday but still not getting solution.I have tried  -

```
Bitmap bitmap=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
and
Bitmap bitmap=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

but still returning null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND parameter rather FULL_SCREEN_KIND. MINI_KIND is work with me above 4.0+

Comment: sometime if video quality is not good it return null bitmap..So check it also

Comment: Sir i have tried using HD video too but same issue.

Comment: even I am getting the same issue. @rb16 can you please tell me how did you resolve the issue.

Comment: @rb16 even I am getting the same issue.can you please tell me how did you resolve the issue

Comment: @Prathyusha please see my answer.that was work for me.Hope that one solve your problem.

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`createVideoThumbnail(String filePath, int kind)` supports `MINI_KIND or MICRO_KIND` as kind only.

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html.

try one of those...
regards

note: `May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported.`

Comment: Thanks Sir for reply.I have tried both MINI_KIND and MICRO_KIND but in both case it returns null.Is i missing something?

Comment: sir, when i click on list item then video is playing properly.so i don't think video is corrupted or not supported by device.

Comment: And same video is playing properly on other device and create thumb. i have try many times by uninstalling app and  cleaned project.

Comment: @malimo I am facing the same problem. Do you have any idea to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to get a bitmap from a video URL.

```
public Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath){
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
            // no headers included
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
        else
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null)
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some devices can't play and can't create thumbnails for videos, that placed on internal memory.
Check it, and move your video to SD Card before thumbnails creating.

Comment: Do you have some kind of source that confirms this? User permission doesn't depends on sdcard or internal memory.

Comment: that video is not on device,i am just passing path of video file and file stored at remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  my solution to fix this problem-

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: again getting same issue

Comment: here is my code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164353/thumbnail-returns-null-on-android-above-version-4-0/27164672?noredirect=1#comment42823062_27164672

Answer (score 0):

If your video located on the external storage requires permission in manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`