# thumbnail returns null on android above version 4.0

Tags: android, thumbnails

I am getting the same[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048825/thumb-from-video-url-returns-null-on-android-4-0-and-above)
issue

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{


    ImageView imgVie;

    Bitmap bmp,extBmp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        imgVie = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);          
        String path =   "http://202.65.154.108:8080/VODStream/lokesh.stream.mp4";
        bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);

        if(bmp!=null)
        {

            extBmp =    ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bmp, 300, 300);
            imgVie.setImageBitmap(extBmp);
        }

        if(bmp==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry your bitmap returns null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



}
```

when run this application in nexus4s its entering into if condition.In all other phones it moving to else.
do you have any suggestions.

Comment: For me the path wasnt corect. Could you check that? and paste more of that code here.

Comment: Bingo, that is the issue infact. The parameter path here refers to the file-path where your video is saved locally. Not sure if its possible directly from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If your video is on the external storage requires permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0):

1)- Sometime if video quality is poor , video is corrupt or format is not supported it returns null bitmap.

2)- createVideoThumbnail(String filePath, int kind) supports MINI_KIND or MICRO_KIND as kind only in      4.0+.

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html.
try one of those...

3)- Some devices can't play and can't create thumbnails for videos, that placed on internal memory. Check it, and move your video to SD Card before thumbnails creating.

4)Check your path of the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048825/thumb-from-video-url-returns-null-on-android-4-0-and-above  I took high quality videos,I tried with all KINDS and I am getting file path from server location.

Comment: Video is not the corrupted one,because when i click on the line its playing the video

Comment: what might be the other reason for this.

Comment: Here is code ......                                         final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, null);
imageColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplication().getContentResolver(),
            imageCursor.getInt(imageColumnIndex),MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

Comment: If you make call to MINI_KIND instead, you will be able to get the right thumbnail.